# もはや used with しか

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I know that もはや+negative verb means "no longer", and しか+negative verb means "only", "nothing but". But seeing them used together, as in the following sentence, got me a little confused.

> 多くの帯刀者はもはや脅威でしかありません！

Does this translate as:

> Many taitosha are no longer only a threat!

or

> Many taitosha are only a threat by now!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is nothing but (でしかない) + anymore (もはや) -> "is nothing anymore but" <- Does it not make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X でしかない === . . . has the only value (usefulness) of X

> 帯銃者は, もはや 脅威でしかありません

Gun-carriers are now nothing more than a threat.

Gun-carriers  now constitute nothing more than a threat.

Gun-carriers  now don't mean [ anything other than a threat ].

A gun-carrier  now represents  [ nothing but a threat ].

A gun-carrier  now doesn't represent  [ anything but a dangerous threat ].

> I know that もはや+negative verb means "no longer",

Yes, that's right.

もはや doesn't have the meaning of NOT built into it.

もはや means that [something that was true] is not true (no longer true) after time T.

[something that was true] == carrying guns around (on one's person) had some value to society.

But this explanation doesn't match the following definitions completely.
Or maybe it does.

> dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220077/meaning/m0u/
>
> もはや【最早】とは。［副］
>
> 1. ある事態が実現しようとしているさま。早くも。まさに。「―今年も暮れようとしている」
> 2. ある事態が変えられない ところ まで進んでいるさま。今となっては。もう。「―如何ともしがたい」「―これまで」

---

i wanted to add that ... 　　(for the 2nd sense just above)　it seems that  もはや is used only when there is a negation (in the text) or there is a negative sense (to describe the current state).

もはや自由な時代になったんだよ 　　　is uncommon or impossible.

今や自由な時代になったんだよ 　　　is much better.

Comment: So もはや can be translated as "now" (and not "no longer"), implying that in the past it wasn't like it is now?

Answer (score 2):

This sentence means "Many taitosha are nothing more than a treat". It's confusing because "しかありません" becomes affirmative when translated on western languages, but it's still a negative in the sense of Japanese grammar.

Answer (score 0):

多くの帯刀者はもはや脅威でしかありません！
With so many swordsmen out there now, it is impossible not to consider them a threat!