# use of もはや in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 考えれば考えるほど、もはや「詰んでいる」としか思えない。

context: speaker is fucked

> The more i think about it, the more... hopeless it seems???

just stabbing at the last part based on the context, i did read

[もはや used with しか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39069/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AF%E3%82%84-used-with-%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B/39070)

but the explanations for もはや + しかないare very difficult to digest.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The more I think about it, the more I realize that, *at this point* (=もはや), *the only possible conclusion* (=としか思えない) is that it's already a checkmate (=詰んでいる)."

もはや is "already, already at this point".  You can think of it as a more dramatic もう.  としか思えない is "I cannot think of it except as…", that is, "the only possible conclusion is that…"

A less clumsy translation would be something like: "The more I think about it, the more I realize it's already over for me" (or her/me/them/etc.)